# serializeArray получить значения формы

Tags: jquery, forms, serialize

Здравствуйте! 
Есть вот такой код:
https://jsfiddle.net/alcheez/h5vjodx3/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
            $("#results").append(this.value);
          
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
</form>

<button>Serialize form values</button>

<div id="results"></div>
```

У меня получилось получить значение формы и теперь мне нужно, допустим, вставить эти значения в простой абзац, ну например:

```
<p>Здравствуйте, моё имя (Mickey), а моя фамилия (Mouse).</p>
```

Я не понимаю, как этого можно добиться, как записать значения полей формы в нужные мне места, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно просто сформировать абзац, можно это сделать так:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#results").append('<p>Здравствуйте, моё имя ' + 
    $('form input[name="FirstName"]').val() + ', а моя фамилия ' + 
    $('form input[name="LastName"]').val() + '.</p>');        
});
```

либо так:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var x = $("form").serializeArray();
    var values = {};
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
        values[this.name] = this.value;          
    });
    $("#results").append('<p>Здравствуйте, моё имя ' + values.FirstName + 
        ', а моя фамилия ' + values.LastName + '.</p>');
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое, Вы очень помогли

Comment: а если мне нужно будет, например, файл какой нибудь генерировать, и туда вставлять эти значения?
я имею ввиду, можно ли как то использовать эти данные вне функции?